# c# page_unload firing together with after page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i want to delete some files when a user closes the browser.

I'm using the `page_unload` method shown below:

```
   protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);
        string[] uploadedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/testPdfIn"));
        foreach (string uploaded in uploadedFiles)
        {
            File.Delete(uploaded);
        }
    }
```

but the `page_unload` method will just fire right after the page load, deleting the files in folder without the user even closing the browser.

Is there a way to stop the `page_unload` from firing right after loading and only firing when user closes the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better you detect the browser close event and than call ther server side function using ajax will do for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(window).unload(function () {

   jQuery.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:49591/filedelete.aspx", async: false });
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So this is a function to detect the browser close event? If so, how to i invoke it so that the delete file method will be fired?

Comment: @SamuelTang - you need to put ajax call as i did in my code check ...calling serverside method with jquery...will do for you

Answer (score 1):

This Is How it shoud be work ,If You want to do something in page unload .use **window.onbeforeunload**

Answer (score 1):

`Page.Unload` does not work how you think it works.
`Page.Unload` is fired at the end of the `Page` [life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), not when the browser is closed:

> The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered,
>   sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. At this point, page
>   properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and cleanup is
>   performed.

The code-behind methods are server-side while the browser being closed is a client-side event.

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Unload` has nothing to do with browser close. Unload event occurs once all the page element/page has been loaded completely.

You should consider putting your file deletion code in `session_end` in global.asax file

Comment: Tried this out, but i need the files to be deleted right away after the browser is closed.